# How can i fix MYSQL error in php consumer?

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq, consumer

i have this dockerfile for php-consumer:
`

```
FROM node:latest as node
FROM php:8.0-fpm

COPY --from=mlocati/php-extension-installer:1.2 /usr/bin/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

COPY --from=node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /usr/local/lib/node_modules
COPY --from=node /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
RUN ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpq-dev \
    wget \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    git \
    php7.*-xml \
    pkg-config \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    librabbitmq-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libicu-dev g++
RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install intl

ENV CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -D_GNU_SOURCE"
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg=/usr/include/ && \
    docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql zip curl sockets pcntl

RUN install-php-extensions \
    decimal \
    pdo_mysql \
    intl \
    amqp \
    bcmath \
    pcntl \
    sockets \
    xsl

RUN pecl install -o -f redis \
    &&  rm -rf /tmp/pear \
    &&  docker-php-ext-enable redis

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libxslt1-dev -y && docker-php-ext-install xsl

RUN curl -S https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY consume.sh /consumer/consume.sh

WORKDIR /workdir

ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/consumer/consume.sh"]
```

`

This consume.sh:
`

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 10;
/workdir/bin/console messenger:consume >&1;
```

`

This messenger.yaml:
`

```
framework:
  messenger:
    transports:
      movies:
        dsn: "%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%"
        options:
          vhost: "/"

    routing:
      App\Message\Tmdb\MovieRequestedMessage: movies
```

`

`

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://user_name:password@mysql/database_name?serverVersion=5.7"
```

`

And when i dispatch the message, i got this error in php_consumer:
`02:46:24 WARNING   [messenger] Error thrown while handling message App\Message\Tmdb\MovieRequestedMessage. Sending for retry #1 using 1000 ms delay. Error: "Handling "App\Message\Tmdb\MovieRequestedMessage" failed: An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory" ["class" => "App\Message\Tmdb\MovieRequestedMessage","retryCount" => 1,"delay" => 1000,"error" => "Handling "App\Message\Tmdb\MovieRequestedMessage" failed: An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory","exception" => Symfony\Component\Messenger\Exception\HandlerFailedException { …}]

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
  php-consumer:
container_name: php_consumer
build:
  context: docker/php-consumer
env_file:
  - .env
volumes:
  - .:/project
depends_on:
  - mysql
  - rabbitmq
  - php-cli
  - php-fpm
environment:
  - "MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=${MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN}"
  - "DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}"
networks:
  - network
```

I tried to change mysql to mysql container ip, but it doesn't work.

I would be very grateful for any clarification, and for any help. Thank you so much!

Comment: where oes database_url come from? the sqlerror implies its looking for the default (local) socket you not have and no remote host was set.

Comment: @Rufinus it comes from a .env file. And in PHP-fpm it works properly. I edit question and add docker-compose.yml code

Comment: any special chars in your password? can break the escaping